# How to check App Pool BEFORE start or stop in yml pipeline

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I want to stop and start my app pool so it picks up the new dll files I have deployed.  However, if the app pool is already stopped, I get an error. Is there any way to check for the app pool status before attempting to stop and start?

I have found the yaml tasks to stop and start but I do not have the ability to install the powershell module (import-module WebAdministration) on my servers (else I would just do it with powershell).

My code is

```
  - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
    inputs:
      IISDeploymentType: 'IISApplicationPool'
      ActionIISApplicationPool: 'StopAppPool'
      StartStopRecycleAppPoolName: '$(ApplicationAppPool)'

    # do stuff here

    - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
      inputs:
        IISDeploymentType: 'IISApplicationPool'
        ActionIISApplicationPool: 'StartAppPool'
        StartStopRecycleAppPoolName: '$(ApplicationPoolName)'
```

Update: I found a ticket open regarding this so I'm guessing this is a known issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21&q=using+IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup